# Is it possible to merge questions?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

Is possible for two questions to be merged?

[This user](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/3127/filippo) posted the same question identically here and on Stack Overflow. Both questions got good answers. And now the Stack Overflow question was migrated here.

Of course one could be marked as the duplicate of the other, but that wouldn't do the answers justice. It would be better if the answers could be merged onto one of the questions and the other be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, moderators can merge questions and I have just done so for the questions in question.